# Error: The security token included in the request is invalid - AWS DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

The file is stored in `.js` script and located in AWS S3.

```
AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-2",
  //endpoint: 'dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
  accessKeyId: "name",
  secretAccessKey: "pass"
});

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
var params = {
    TableName : "table_name",
    ProjectionExpression:"company, link, budget",
    KeyConditionExpression: "company = :Adidas"
};
dynamodb.query(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

I am trying to get data from DynamoDB, but instead get this:

> Error: The security token included in the request is invalid.
>       at Request.extractError (aws-sdk.js:96980)
>       at Request.callListeners (aws-sdk.js:98762)
>       at Request.emit (aws-sdk.js:98736)
>       at Request.emit (aws-sdk.js:97899)
>       at Request.transition (aws-sdk.js:97626)
>       at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (aws-sdk.js:101148)
>       at aws-sdk.js:101160
>       at Request. (aws-sdk.js:97642)
>       at Request. (aws-sdk.js:97901)
>       at Request.callListeners (aws-sdk.js:98772) "UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the
>   request is invalid.
>       at Request.extractError (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aws-sdk/2.22.0/aws-sdk.js:96980:27)
>       at Request.callListeners (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aws-sdk/2.22.0/aws-sdk.js:98762:20)
>       at Request.emit (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aws-sdk/2.22.0/aws-sdk.js:98736:10)
>       at Request.emit (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aws-sdk/2.22.0/aws-sdk.js:97899:14)
>       at Request.transition (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aws-sdk/2.22.0/aws-sdk.js:97626:10)
>       at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aws-sdk/2.22.0/aws-sdk.js:101148:12)
>       at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aws-sdk/2.22.0/aws-sdk.js:101160:10
>       at Request. (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aws-sdk/2.22.0/aws-sdk.js:97642:9)
>       at Request. (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aws-sdk/2.22.0/aws-sdk.js:97901:12)
>       at Request.callListeners (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aws-sdk/2.22.0/aws-sdk.js:98772:18)"

How can I make this work?

Comment: Hmmm... "name" and "pass"?  Does your accessKeyId begin with `AKIA` or `ASIA`?  If not, that's not an accessKeyId you're using here.

Comment: Make sure you have the DynamoDB table on us-west-2 region? Region is a very important parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message indicates a problem with credentials. Embedding credentials in local variables in a script poses a security risk. Please try to use one of the [recommended methods](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html) to configure your client credentials, in decreasing order of preference:

1. AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) roles (for example, in EC2 instance profiles or Lambda execution roles)
2. A shared credentials file (~/.aws/credentials)
3. Environment variables
4. A JSON file on disk

Comment: Thanks. It works for me. I just changed my ~/.aws/credentials with a key in aws.

Comment: I am trying to do it, but I currently have no results.
My folders are like this:
proyect/.aws/config.json

and my config.json:
{
    "accessKeyId": "MYKEY",
    "secretAccessKey": "MYKEY",
    "region": "us-east-1"
}

Comment: In my case I had to include my `aws_session_token` as well for it to work, client id and secret weren't enough. Something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. But in my case, it turned out that I incorrectly passed credentials. I used AWS SDK v3, but tried to do it in the AWS SDK v2 way - the API is almost the same, so I didn't check it at once.

So if you are using AWS SDK v3, you should do it the following way (if you have configured your credentials via `aws configure --profile profile_name`):

```js
let config = { region: 'us-east-1' };
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    // it is needed only for development, so a dynamic import is used
    const { fromIni } = await import('@aws-sdk/credential-provider-ini');
    config = {
        region: 'us-west-2',
        credentials: fromIni({
            profile: 'profile_name',
        }),
    };
}
const db = new DynamoDB(config)
```

Or an alternative way:

```js
import { loadSharedConfigFiles } from '@aws-sdk/shared-ini-file-loader';
const configFiles = await loadSharedConfigFiles();
const db = new DynamoDB({
    region: configFiles.configFile['profile_name'].region || 'us-east-1',
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: configFiles.credentialsFile['profile_name'].aws_access_key_id,
        secretAccessKey: configFiles.credentialsFile['profile_name'].aws_secret_access_key,
    }
});
```